# How to use CXF with SDO?

Tags: web-services, cxf, sdo

I try to build a CXF-based client application for an existing web-service using 'Contract-First' pattern.

The XSDs are quite complex so I am looking for a way to utilize something like SDO, avoiding code-generation for a WSDL. WSDL2Java tool makes 20K-line classes.
I have already used SDO in IBM WebSphere ESB, I wish I could reuse my previous code.

I can't find a way of doing this with CXF, 
only this: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/sdo.html.

The text regarding SDO seems to be outdated because WSDL2Java tool does not support a "-db sdo" parameter anymore.
It says:

```
WSDL2Java -o D:/wsdl2java_out -d sdo -uri WS.wsdl
...
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException: No proper databinding has taken place
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the Axis2 wsdl2java command and not the CXF wsdl2java.